# Issue in php script for android app

Tags: php

I have a **showProduct.php** file from where i want to call a function `showProduct()` in another file. In `showProduct()` i want to extract all rows from database and to **showProduct.php** file. the issue is that when i return the array only last row is showing. I want to show all the rows.
The **showProduct.php** is:

```
<?php
require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';
$response = array();
$result = array();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
$db = new DbOperations();
$result = $db->showProduct();
if(!empty($result))
{
    $response["prod_name"] = $result["prod_name"];
    $response["prod_desc"] = $result["prod_desc"];
    $response["prod_image"] = $result["prod_image"];
}
else
{
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "products are not shown";
}
} 
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

and showProduct() function is:

```
public function showProduct(){
    $menu = array();
    $query = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE 1");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $menu['prod_name'] = $row['prod_name'] ;
            $menu['prod_desc'] = $row['prod_desc'] ;
            $menu['prod_image'] = $row['prod_image'];
    }
    return $menu;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your function, you are just overwriting the last data each time, you need to build this data up.  Create an array with the new data and use `$menu[]` to add this new data to the list of menus...

```
public function showProduct(){
    $menu = array();
    $query = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE 1");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $newMenu = [];    // Clear array to ensure no details left over
            $newMenu['prod_name'] = $row['prod_name'] ;
            $newMenu['prod_desc'] = $row['prod_desc'] ;
            $newMenu['prod_image'] = $row['prod_image'];

            $menu[] = $newMenu;
    }
    return $menu;
}
```